# Why does java hashmap treeify the bin at the count of 8 and untreeify at the count of 6?

Tags: java, hashmap

Please enlighten me. I can only imagine that this situation can avoid the  treeify and untreeify frequently while the count of the bin is 8.

```
/**
 * The bin count threshold for using a tree rather than list for a
 * bin.  Bins are converted to trees when adding an element to a
 * bin with at least this many nodes. The value must be greater
 * than 2 and should be at least 8 to mesh with assumptions in
 * tree removal about conversion back to plain bins upon
 * shrinkage.
 */
static final int TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8;

/**
 * The bin count threshold for untreeifying a (split) bin during a
 * resize operation. Should be less than TREEIFY_THRESHOLD, and at
 * most 6 to mesh with shrinkage detection under removal.
 */
static final int UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 6;
```

Actually, I am asking why the values are not the same. Can you show me the specific statics about the reason why they use the different count?

Comment: A 'good hash table' will be one that contains objects whose class defines a hash function that produces good distributions.  A good hash table will have an appropriate number of bins so that hash collisions are infrequent.  The constants above describe the performance characteristics of the hash table when there have been sufficient hash collisions so that bins begin to become 'too full'.  A linear search is the most efficient search strategy when the number of items in the bin is small.  A tree is most efficient when the number of items in the bin is large.

Comment: Are you asking why these specific thresholds are used, or why the values are not the same?

Comment: I would assume they are different as otherwise it would both be allowed to treeify and untreeify at the same count (which would be problematic), and that the difference is 2 and not 1 to prevent the map spending too much time switching between either mode when an item is removed and subsequently readded (or vice versa). However, your question requires intimate knowledge of Java's `HashMap` implementation and the actual design decisions taken. You are unlikely to get a real answer here, except for guesses like mine. That makes your question off topic is it would primarily yield opinions.

Comment: @AndyTurner Autually,I am asking why the values are not the same.Can you show me the specific statics about the reason why they use the different count?

Comment: *"Autually,I am asking why the values are not the same.Can you show me the specific statics about the reason why they use the different count?"* ... there is probably no analytical answer to this question.  The Java Collections Framework is very old by now.  With each iteration of the platform, the HashMap implementation has been tweaked, optimized, and steadily improved.  In Java 8 (I think) the latest implementation was dropped in, and this yielded measurable performance improvements for some systems.  The thresholds you see are likely the result of careful tuning and that's all.

Comment: @scottb Thank you.Actually,this question was asked in a job interview.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good question.  Sorry it was close-voted by folks who don't know the answer ;-).  Anyway... the reason the thresholds are different is to limit the time wasted by converting between lists and trees.  If the thresholds were the same, and you repeatedly and and remove an item from the same bucket, then a conversion would be performed *every time*.  The difference between thresholds ensures that, once a list is converted to a tree, you need to remove *3* items from the bucket before it changes back.  Then you need to add *3* more before it changes to a tree again, etc.

Comment: Just to be clear, the purpose is to optimize the *amortized* cost of the add + remove operations, which is (close to) how we expect to count the cost of a HashMap.  The treeifying limits the *worst case* cost.  This is a nice feature, but not if it increases the amoritized cost unduly, which is why the threshold difference is important.  You may not see any of this supported by documentation, but that is absolutely the reason for the difference.  I'm impressed that whatever company you interviewed with thought to ask.   I do interviews all the time and wouldn't expect anyone to know, really.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Good point,I got the same answer at First.Actually,it's one of my friend who interview the Alibaba in China.

Answer (score 1):

Hashmap is the implementation of hashtable data structure. When we insert a key, value pair , using a hash function system will identify the hash value for the key and insert into a corresponding bin. If you insert another key, value pair and hash value of the second key also provide the same value it will go to the same bin. This scenario is called hash collision. If the size of the bin is small, while searching for the element later, List/array implementation of bin provide better performance. Otherwise bin size is large a binary tree may help to identify the key easily. What you have noticed is a a performance optimization of the hashmap.